# Static files are not loading in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-static

Why I am receiving files can't be found error while loading all the static files even after setting everything correctly.

**ERROR**

[image]

**CODE:**

**Admin Section**

**- settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')
```

**- urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Welcome.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('Authentication.urls')),
    path('ad/', include('Ads.urls')),
    path('user/', include('UserDashboard.urls')),
    path('admin/', include('AdminDashboard.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**Apps Section**

**- template**

```
<link href="{% static 'css/user/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**- Folder Structure**

[image]

Comment: You told it that the `/static/` URL should be routed to the `BASE_DIR`.  I think you want `BASE_DIR + '/static'`.

Comment: The error which is generated after this, `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR + '')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'`

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because the Django project searches your static folders in the wrong place.

This will work:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```